# Какой аналог attach() есть для связи belongsTo, Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

**Какой аналог attach() есть для связи belongsTo, Laravel?**

Есть таблица users и books

И мне при добавлении (а так же при редактировании) новой книги, нужно выбрать (поменять, при редактировании) её автора из списка уже имеющихся

Список в виде `<input type="radio">` вывел[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при вводе названия, выборе жанров и автора, всё указывается кроме автора

Добавление

```
<div class="container">
        <a href="{{ url('books') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Вернуться</a>
        <hr>

        <h2>Добавить новую книгу</h2>
        <form method="POST" action="{{route('books.store')}}">
            @csrf
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input name="book" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Название книги">

                @error('book')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Авторы:</h3>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <input type="radio" name="name" value="{{$user->id}}">
                    <label>{{$user->name}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
                @error('name')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Жанры:</h3>
                @foreach($genres as $genre)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="{{$genre->id}}">
                    <label>{{$genre->genre}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
                @error('genres[]')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Создать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Редактирование

```
    <div class="container">
        <a href="{{ url('books') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Вернуться</a>
        <hr>

        <h2>Редактировать книгу: {{$book->book}}</h2>

        <form method="POST" action="{{route('books.update', $book->id)}}">
            @csrf

            @method('PUT')

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input name="book" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Название книги" value="{{$book->book}}">
                @error('book')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Авторы:</h3>
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <input type="radio" name="name" value="{{$user->id}}">
                    <label>{{$user->name}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
                @error('name')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h3>Жанры:</h3>
                @foreach($genres as $genre)
                    <input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="{{$genre->id}}"
                    @if($book->genres->where('id', $genre->id)->count())
                        checked="checked"
                        @endif
                    >
                    <label>{{$genre->genre}}</label>
                    <br>
                @endforeach
                @error('genres[]')
                <p class="text-red-500">{{$message}}</p>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Редактировать</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Controller на добавление

```
    public function create()
    {
        return view("admin.books.create", [
            "book" => [],
            "genres" => Genre::get(),
            "users" => User::get()
            ]);
    }

    public function store(BookFormRequest $request)
    {
        $book = Book::create($request->validated());
        if($request->input('users')){
            $book->users()->associate($request->input('users'));
        }

        if($request->input('genres')){
            $book->genres()->attach($request->input('genres'));
        }
        return redirect(route('books', $book));
    }
```

И редактирование

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $book = Book::findOrFail($id);

        return view("admin.books.edit", [
            "book" => $book,
            "genres" => Genre::get(),
            "users" => User::get()
        ]);
    }

    public function update(BookFormRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $book = Book::findOrFail($id);
        $book->update($request->validated());

        ($book->users()->count) ?
            $book->users()->update($request->only('users')) :

        $book->genres()->detach();
        if($request->input('genres')) {
            $book->genres()->attach($request->input('genres'));
        }

        return redirect(route('books'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение: метод `associate`, а затем `save()`:

```
$book->users()->associate($request->input('users'));
$book->save();
```